# Segmentation fault 11 on Macbook m1 chip

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a problem and i don t know if is a problem with my Macbook or my code. Thank you for help!

I also tried to look through the settings, I really don't understand why it doesn't work and why it gives this error. I am a beginner and I have the code from a colleague at college

I really don't know what details to give, I kept searching and couldn't find an answer

I uninstall the vscode and install.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Farmacie
{
    char *denumire;
    int nr_angajati;
    float *salarii;
    int an_infiintare;
};
struct Farmacie initializare(const char *denumire, int nr_angajati, float *salarii, int an_infiintare)
{
    struct Farmacie f;
    f.nr_angajati = nr_angajati;
    f.an_infiintare = an_infiintare;
    f.denumire = malloc((strlen(denumire) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(f.denumire, denumire);
    f.salarii = malloc(sizeof(float) * nr_angajati);
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_angajati; i++)
    {
        f.salarii[i] = salarii[i];
    }
    return f;
}

void afisareFarmacie(struct Farmacie f)
{
    printf("Denumire: %s, infiintata in: %d", f.denumire, f.an_infiintare);
    printf(", nr. angajati: %d, cu salariile: ", f.nr_angajati);
    for (int i = 0; i < f.nr_angajati; i++)
        printf("%5.2f, ", f.salarii[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
struct Farmacie copiere(const struct Farmacie f2)
{
    struct Farmacie aux;
    aux.an_infiintare = f2.an_infiintare;
    aux.nr_angajati = f2.nr_angajati;
    aux.denumire = malloc((strlen(f2.denumire) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(aux.denumire, f2.denumire);
    aux.salarii = malloc(sizeof(float) * f2.nr_angajati);
    for (int i = 0; i < f2.nr_angajati; i++)
    {
        aux.salarii[i] = f2.salarii[i];
    }
    return aux;
}

struct Farmacie *adaugaFarmacieInVector(struct Farmacie *farmacii, struct Farmacie f, int *nr)
{
    *nr = *nr + 1;
    struct Farmacie *aux = malloc(sizeof(struct Farmacie) * (*nr));
    for (int i = 0; i < *nr - 1; i++)
        aux[i] = farmacii[i];
    aux[*nr - 1] = copiere(f);
    return aux;
}

int calculNrAngajati(struct Farmacie *farmacii, int nr)
{
    int nrTotalAngajati = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        nrTotalAngajati += farmacii[i].nr_angajati;
    }
    return nrTotalAngajati;
}

struct Farmacie citireFisier(FILE *f)
{
    struct Farmacie aux;
    char buffer[30];
    fscanf(f, "%s", buffer);
    aux.denumire = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    strcpy(aux.denumire, buffer);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &aux.nr_angajati);
    aux.salarii = malloc(sizeof(float) * aux.nr_angajati);
    for (int i = 0; i < aux.nr_angajati; i++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%f", &aux.salarii[i]);
    }
    fscanf(f, "%d", &aux.an_infiintare);
    return aux;
}

int main()
{

    FILE *file = fopen("farmacie.txt", "r");
    struct Farmacie fis = citireFisier(file);

    afisareFarmacie(fis);
}
```

Comment: You should always check the return values from function like `fopen`, `malloc`, `fscanf`, etc. They can all fail for various reasons.

Comment: [Edit] and show the first 10 lines of so of "farmacie.txt" as properly formatted text.

Comment: It's almost certainly because `fopen("farmacie.txt", "r");` fails, that is it returns `NULL` and then you try to read from this NULL file pointer in `citireFisier`, hence the segfault. Using `fscanf` with a NULL file pointer yields _undefined behaviour_ (google that), and one of the very common manifests of undefined behaviour are segfaults. The reason why `fopen` fails is most likely because the file is not in the current directory of the your program.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would not return structures (or take them as parameters) as it is very costly
2. C programs need to check for error conditions (and you are missing plenty `if`s in your code :) )

```
typedef struct Farmacie
{
    char *denumire;
    size_t nr_angajati;
    float *salarii;
    int an_infiintare;
}Farmacie;

#define MAXSTRINGLENGTH     30

void afisareFarmacie(Farmacie *f)
{
    if(f && f -> denumire && f -> salarii)
    {
        printf("Denumire: %s, infiintata in: %d", f -> denumire, f -> an_infiintare);
        printf(", nr. angajati: %d, cu salariile: ", f -> nr_angajati);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < f -> nr_angajati; i++)
            printf("%5.2f, ", f -> salarii[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else printf("Invalid data\n");
}

Farmacie *citireFisier(FILE *f)
{
    Farmacie *aux;

    if(f)
    {
        aux = malloc(sizeof(*aux));
        if(aux)
        {
            aux -> denumire = malloc(MAXSTRINGLENGTH * sizeof(aux -> denumire[0]));  // do not save memry here
            if(!aux -> denumire) { /* handle allocation error */}
        
            if(!fgets(aux -> denumire, MAXSTRINGLENGTH, f))  { /* handle I/O error */}
            if(fscanf(f, "%zu", &aux -> nr_angajati) != 1)  { /* handle I/O error */}
            aux -> salarii = malloc(sizeof(aux -> salarii[0]) * aux -> nr_angajati);
            if(!aux -> salarii) { /* handle allocation error */}
            for (size_t i = 0; i < aux -> nr_angajati; i++)
            {
                if(fscanf(f, "%f", &aux -> salarii[i]) != 1) { /* handle I/O error */}
            }
            if(fscanf(f, "%d", &aux -> an_infiintare) != 1) { /* handle I/O error */}
        }
    }
    return aux;
}

int main(void)
{

    FILE *file = fopen("farmacie.txt", "r");
    Farmacie *fis = citireFisier(file);

    afisareFarmacie(fis);
    if(file) fclose(file);
    free(fis);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A `Segmentation Fault` occurs when your program tries to access memory that doesn't belong to it. That can be if you try to access a dangling pointer (a pointer whose memory has been freed) or when you try to access a Null Pointer, which can be returned by `fopen` when an error happens, such as when that file doesn't exist.

Because of this it's good practice to check the pointers you receive from `fopen`, `malloc`, etc. before using them in your program like this:

```c
    FILE *file = fopen("farmacie.txt", "r");
    if (!file) {
         //handle error
    }
```

Maybe try to run your program with `gdb` and look at the backtrace to see where it fails.

Comment: Why does this feel like a AI-generated answer?

Comment: @Haris Because a lot of answers sound like that nowadays :/